# Make new column in pandas that checks if file exists

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to make a new column in a pandas dataframe that returns `True` if a path in another columns exists and `False` if it does not exist.

I have the following example:

```
> d = {'file': ["path/to/existing/file", "path/to/nonexisting/file"]}
> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
> df
    file
0   path/to/existing/file
1   path/to/nonexisting/file
```

I would like to make a new column that checks if a dataframe exists. The results would be as follows

```
    file                        exists
0   path/to/existing/file        True
1   path/to/nonexisting/file     False
```

I get an error with the following

```
def file_exists(x):
    x = x.astype(str)
    if os.path.exists(x):
        return True
    else:
        return False
df["exists"] = np.where(file_exists(df["file"]), 1, 0)
```

> TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not Series

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are calling `os.path.exists` on `x`, which is a `Series` object. In reality, you want to apply `os.path.exists` to every element in `x`; something like this could work: `df['file'].astype(str).map(os.path.exists)`.

Comment: Well for one thing your function definition is `file_exists`, but when you call it you are calling `pkl_exists`

Comment: @MarkJ I fixed that typo. Sorry

Comment: @IgorRaush Thanks, `df['exists'] = df['file'].astype(str).map(os.path.exists)` worked for me

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. `df["exists"] = np.where(file_exists(df["file"]), 1, 0)` is quite unidiomatic, for multiple reasons. Also, the `.astype(str)` is unnecessary here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From @IgorRaush 's comment

```py
df['exists'] = df['file'].astype(str).map(os.path.exists)
```